# Uncaught ReferenceError from jQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript

I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: fun is not defined` when the function is defined just below the call.

I simplified as much as possible my script to reproduce the error

```
fun();

function fun() {
}

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => call(resolve, reject));

const call = (success, error) => { };
```

I get this exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fun is not defined
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:545), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:545)
    at text script (jquery.js:7617)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:7592)
    at done (jquery.js:7350)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:7822)
    at Object.send (jquery.js:7845)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:7301)
    at Function._evalUrl (jquery.js:5880)
```

It seems to be working if I remove the `var promise` line or replace `call(resolve, reject)` with `{}`, but I cannot understand why.

> jQuery version 2.0.3

Any idea of why is this happening?

EDIT: I had other problem related to the globalEval of jQuery, and I solved them by moving the jQuery script tag as last one, but still doesn't help with this.

Comment: I don't understand...where do you call `fun()` ? Important parts of the code are missing here. I can't replicate your problem. Please add the code that replicates the problem you are having here or on http://jsfiddle.net. But the error speaks for itself. It's probably a scope related problem.

Comment: @Ionut oops, that slipped out. just missing the top fun()

Comment: I don't see how jQuery is relevant here. Where do you use it?

Comment: @AndrewLi it's jQuery that is causing the exception.

Comment: But that makes no sense. If that's all your code, there's no reason jQuery should be doing anything at all because it's not used...

Comment: @AndrewLi have a look at `Function.globalEval` I didn't investigate why, but apparently it's reading my script and shouting.

Comment: @user4388177, the problem here is that no one will be able to replicate your problem using the code above, unless you add a runnable snippet that shows the exact problem you say you have. We can only suppose what is happening.

Comment: @Ionut that above is exactly the full script I'm running. I can add the html file, but it's pointless as it contains only a couple of script tags one with jQuery and another with my script.

Comment: @user4388177, if that is your only code please make a http://jsfiddle.net and check the console. I don't see the same error. Hint: I only see that `call` is undefined.

Comment: @Ionut I tried; copied and pasted it, but no luck: https://jsfiddle.net/r6wsy93x/

Comment: Actually, it's not easy to reproduce there, don't know how to get the `Promise` type in the fiddle I was using JS and non TS that's why I was getting your same error only before.

Comment: The code as shown in the question gives a *different* error when run: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: call is not defined` because it is using `call` before it is defined.

Comment: That's definitely a problem with the code that needs fixing, but not the one from the question that I'm getting. I'm using a TypeScript project in VS hosted by IIS Express if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        function run() {
            var toReload = "app.js";
            $('script[src="' + toReload + '"]').remove();
            $('<script>').attr('src', toReload).appendTo('head');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was loading my code dynamically and jQuery was getting confused. Moving my script into a script tag before jQuery solved it.